# How to Autolayout Programatically in Standard UITableViewCell for custom UIButton in Right side.

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, autolayout

First of all I've to solve this layout issue programmatically and not in storyboard, because I've defined my buttons via coding not drag & dropped via storyboard,

I've programmed universal iOS app, in which I've few TableView's. I've to add some custom buttons in each `UITableViewCell` Right-side or you can say it I've to add buttons in `trailing` margin of the cell, it works pretty fine in simulator's iPhone7 Plus, but what about iphone 5 or 5s & other iOS devices? here is how it looks in iphone7 Plus & iphone 5s

[image]

what kind of moderation I should do in my program(code) regarding layouts, here is my code in `UITableViewCell` method for defining 4 buttons in cellForRowAtIndexPath method,

```
//Favorite Button

    UIButton *addtoFavsButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [addtoFavsButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"like"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    addtoFavsButton.frame = CGRectMake(370.0f, 0.0f, 50.0f, 45.0f); 
    [cell addSubview:addtoFavsButton];
    [addtoFavsButton addTarget:self
                        action:@selector(addtoFavs:)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:addtoFavsButton];
    [addtoFavsButton setTag:indexPath.row];

// WebView Button

UIButton *webViewButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[webViewButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"web"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
webViewButton.frame = CGRectMake(335.0f, 0.0f, 50.0f, 50.0f);
[cell addSubview:webViewButton];
[webViewButton addTarget:self
                  action:@selector(webView:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.contentView addSubview:webViewButton];
[webViewButton setTag:indexPath.row];


// Twitter Share Button

UIButton *twitterButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[twitterButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
twitterButton.frame = CGRectMake(300.0f, 0.0f, 45.0f, 42.0f);
[cell addSubview:twitterButton];
[twitterButton addTarget:self action:@selector(twitterShare:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.contentView addSubview:twitterButton];
//[twitterButton setTag:indexPath.row];


// Facebook Share Button

UIButton *facebookButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[facebookButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"facebook"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
facebookButton.frame = CGRectMake(265.0f, 0.0f, 45.0f, 42.0f);
[cell addSubview:facebookButton];
[facebookButton addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(facebookShare:event:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.contentView addSubview:facebookButton];
```

Suggest me how to program autolayout these buttons so that all of the buttons should be adjusted starting from right side in any iOS Device.

Comment: i think no need of autolayout just calcuate the frame based on device width

Comment: i added my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are not using autolayout then follow my answer

**step1**

create the one macro for define the device width

```
#define WidthCalculation self.view.frame.size.width
```

**step2**

initially set the frame for your addtoFavsButton , it automatically adjust the screen width

```
addtoFavsButton.frame = CGRectMake(WidthCalculation - 60, 0.0f, 50.0f, 45.0f);
```

thereafter caluculate  the another buttons based on addtoFavsButton

```
webViewButton.frame = CGRectMake(WidthCalculation - (addtoFavsButton.frame.origin.x + 50.0f +10), 0.0f, 50.0f, 50.0f);
```

Comment: Step2, fist line gives accurate result but I tried to move button little bit more right side so I replaced `(WidthCalculation - 60, 0.0f, 50.0f, 45.0f);`  with `(WidthCalculation - 45, 0.0f, 50.0f, 45.0f);` and it gives accurate result in both iphone 7Plus and iphone 5s,  But the second line is not giving comfortable result it gives  button in left most direction i.e very starting point of the `UITableViewCell`so I tried to change & revert values again & again to get some comfortable results how ever it works with following values. **continue reading next comment due to low characters left**

Comment: **sorry for above half comment** `(addtoFavsButton.frame.origin.x - 200), 0.0f, 50.0f, 50.0f);` this thing giving exact near location for my second webViewButton, in iPhone 5s, when I tried it in iphone 7Plus it was not giving me accurate near location i.e skips more space than that of the expected.... 
any idea.?

Comment: addtoFavsButton.frame.origin.x - (webViewButton. size.width + 10), it will automatically adjust the width

Comment: sorry this second method also giving error...
But I succeeded to calculate position of remaining buttons, like this way, **webViewButton** , `webViewButton.frame = CGRectMake(WidthCalculation - 75, 0.0f, 50.0f, 45.0f);`  , **twitterButton** , `twitterButton.frame = CGRectMake(WidthCalculation - 105, 0.0f, 45.0f, 42.0f);`  , **facebookButton** , ` facebookButton.frame = CGRectMake(WidthCalculation - 140, 0.0f, 45.0f, 42.0f);` and tested on three different device's i.e **iphone 7 Plus** , **iPhone 5s**, **iphone SE**. it gives required positions while portrait, but during landscape middle

Comment: when I used to make my device landscape all buttons comes near to the middle but not at that same right ending position. but Still it is better than earlier as it was not working perfectly when I switch devices from 7plus to 5s,  still can we make it better? I mean can i move my buttons at same position when landscape orientation? or for now I've to move on with this ? also I've not tested it on ipad yet, but I think at iPad too their postion will be like as landscape on iphone devices or it will be right as portrait on iphone.... any idea regarding my queries?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the frame of these buttons so that whatever be the width of the device the button will place itself in (x,y) co-ordinates defined in its frame variable. So you have to add auto layout constraints to these buttons to get your required design properly in all devices.

Create your required auto layout constraints using NSLayoutConstraint object and add it to the buttons. 
Refer this link:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_auto_layouts.htm

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is not to the point but helpful & provided lots of information regarding required query .. Going to up-vote